# application on google app engine not loading

Tags: google-app-engine

Since 2 days.. when trying to load the home page at http://achhabachhadev.appspot.com/ I am receiving the following error .. need to know If I can do something to fix it.

Error: Server Error The server encountered an error and could not complete your request. If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.

At the logs level all I see is that the request could not be completed in 1 min. Please tell me is there something else which could be the problem. Any help is welcome.. as it was all working till 2 days ago..

The logs are as given below:

53 / 500 62976ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.79 Safari/535.11 I 2012-03-15 04:41:49.013 javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext I 2012-03-15 04:42:19.717 javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'ICCFinal02' W 2012-03-15 04:42:42.245 Error for / com.google.apphosting.runtime.HardDeadlineExceededError: This request (80d56e654b79f25b) started at 2012/03/15 11:41:41.284 UTC and was st W 2012-03-15 04:42:42.245 at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthentic C 2012-03-15 04:42:42.293 Uncaught exception from servlet com.google.apphosting.runtime.HardDeadlineExceededError: This request (80d56e654b79f25b) started at 2012/03/15 11:41:4 I 2012-03-15 04:42:42.315 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This requ W 2012-03-15 04:42:42.315 A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit.

Comment: Is your app use the master/slave datastore instead of HRD?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try re-deploying? I've noticed that every once in a while the appservers get hung up and a redeploy is required to fix it.

Comment: I had changed the default version to a older version as you suggested and it works now. In the newer version we had added a filter to check all requests if they were a jsonp request or not to handle cross domain requests, could that be a reason for the newer version to not work?

Comment: Possibly, but I actually meant to deploy your new version again which would spin up new servers. Sometimes they get hung up.